# Having to restart xinetd service to connect via telnet

Tags: linux, centos5, telnet

In my environment I have a linux server running CentOS 5. I have setup a telnet service on this server in order to connect via telnet. However, after some time I try to connect and I get this error: `This session is no longer connected`.

Once I restart the xinetd service, this message goes away and I am able to once again telnet in. Any ideas on how I can debug this issue or what logs I can check out to see what may be causing this error? Thanks in advance for any advice or help you can recommend.

Comment: Why are you using telnet and not ssh?

Comment: Short answer: the developers voted to use telnet, and also continue to use a client software from a company that no longer exists from the 1990's. I am working hard to present a solution to replace this software. For now I have no other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your telnet service messages will appear in `/var/log/messages`. The service is very stable under RHEL/CentOS. There's a chance that this could be an issue with your clients. Grep your log output for something like the following:

```
Jul 19 21:17:59 NOT-brazzers telnetd[4939]: ttloop: peer died: EOF
```

I'm in a similar situation, having to support legacy client/server software that relies on telnet access. For my EL5 systems, the telnet configuration file looks like the following. Restart the xinetd service to apply any changes:

## /etc/xinetd.d/telnet

```
# default: on
# description: The telnet server serves telnet sessions; it uses \
#       unencrypted username/password pairs for authentication.
service telnet
{
        disable = no
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        server          = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        per_source = UNLIMITED
}
```

Comment: Hello ewwhite, this looks very promising. I will test over the next few days and report back as "answered" if it works properly. Thanks for all your information and help!

Comment: So far, no more issues with my previous problem. Thanks ewwhite for your simple solution!